# How to connect SQLite with my C# application

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite

i have a problem with making a local database into my c# project and creating it..
I tried first with making a Microsoft Sql Server but the problem is that i need to make app which should run on every pc. The app should input data from user , and collect it to the database, and on every start of program, the database should be filled with the leftover of earlier input.. What you suggest me to do?

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking for here. You should provide a [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example). You say "should run on every pc", do you want a local database on each PC, so that each user's data is isolated or are you looking for a shared database that each PC will communicate to and share the same data?

Comment: @PhilThomas you swapped the url with the text... :P

Comment: I wish local database on each PC

Answer (score 3):

First to connect your c# application with sqlite you should start with getting connection string

```
    private static string executableLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    private static string oldconnectionstring = Path.Combine(executableLocation, "YourDB.db");
    private static string connectionString = "Data Source =" + oldconnectionstring.ToString();
```

After getting connection, to add your input to database follow below steps

```
 using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                //Open connection to DB
                conn.Open(); 

                //Query to be fired                   
                string sql = "Your Query to insert rows";

                //Executing the query
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    //Executing the query                    
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                //Close connection to DB
                conn.Close();

            }
```

Comment: I am getting error:
 The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: Please provide the exact error you are getting while using the above code. As it is working fine for me.